# Product representation of a bounded analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be a bounded and analytic function in $|z|<1$ and $|f(z)|<1$ in $|z|<1$. Let $\{a_k\},\; k =1,2...$ denote the zeros of $f(z)$, which are arranged $0 < |a_k| \leq |a_{k+1}| < 1$. The function
$$
b_n(z)=\prod_{k=1}^n |a_k|\frac{1-(z/a_k)}{1-\overline{a_k}z}
$$
has the property that it is analytic in $|z|\leq 1$ with modulus $1$ on $|z|=1$.

**QUESTION:**

Why the inequality $|f(z)/b_n(z)|\leq 1$ holds and why it holds when $n\to\infty$ as well?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The main point is if $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n(z)$ converges to an analytic function or not. If it does, the bound $ \le 1$ follows from the maximum modulus principle